# Why does Make prefer the implicit rule over the rule listed in the Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to wrap my head around why Make is using a certain rule to compile my code. Here is a minimal example:

- Makefile

  ```
    CC := gcc
    CFLAGS := -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration

    targets := main1 main2
    obj_targets := $(patsubst %,%.o,$(targets))

    src_lib := add.c
    obj_lib := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(src_lib))

    all: $(targets)

    %: %.o $(obj_lib)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -static -o $@ $^

    .PHONY: all
  ```
- add.c: `int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`
- main1.c: `int main(void) { return add(1,2); }`
- main2.c: `int main(void) { return add(3,4); }`

When running `make` I get the following:

```
$ make
gcc -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration    main1.c   -o main1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBsxlMV.o: in function `main':
main1.c:(.text.startup+0x11): undefined reference to `add'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: main1] Error 1
```

My intent is to indicate through `%: %.o $(obj_lib)` that each target depends on all of the object files, so that the target's `.o` file will be linked with `add.o`. However, what I am observing instead is that Make is using the implicit rule for compiling a `.c` file to an executable, which fails since `add.o` isn't being linked in.

Why is Make using the implicit rule instead of the rule that I defined?
How can I get Make to compile my targets using the command I specified there?

Comment: There's no mention in your makefile of `add.o`.  Where do you expect it to come from?  I see that your makefile has `$(wildcard lib/*.c)`.  Did you mean `lib/add.c` where you write `add.c` and `lib/add.o` where you wrote `add.o`?

Comment: Yep that's 100% correct. I had meant `lib/add.c`. I have now changed the Makefile to be consistent with the `add.c` naming.

Comment: So, does the makefile you show here now actually reflect the actual setup you have?  In your message you say it should be `lib/add.c` but in the makefile here you use `add.c`, not `lib/add.c`.  Without know exactly what you have we can't help you solve your problem.  Also, it's best if you show the make command you entered and the exact output you got (cut and paste, please) as that often makes it obvious what the problem is.

Comment: My apologies, that was unclear. Locally I moved the file `lib/add.c` to `add.c` and changed the Makefile to compensate. The exact command I run is just make. I have amended the question with this information, and edited my answer to fully demonstrate the non-working and working versions. Thank you for your continued interest in this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that make always uses the shortest chain of implicit rules.  So, if make can find a rule `%.x -> %.y` and another rule `%.x -> %.z -> %.y`, it will always choose the first one.

Make doesn't treat built-in and user-defined rules differently from each other, except that user-defined rules are searched first before built-in rules.

In your situation, you have a built-in rule that knows how to create a binary from a source file with the same name, and a rule you defined that knows how to create a binary from an object file and another chained rule that builds the object file from the source file.  So make chooses the first one.

You can remove that built-in rule with:

```
%: %.c
```

as you did (you don't have to remove the `%.o : %.c` rule).  Alternatively you can use a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html), which creates an explicit rule:

```
all: $(targets)

$(targets): %: %.o $(obj_lib)
        ...
```

Because this is a form of explicit rule, no implicit rule (like pattern rules) will be used.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. The first sentence is the reasoning I was looking for, and the static pattern is the way I will be solving this going forward. However, searching online, I'm not able to find any documentation w.r.t. the shortest chain being preferred. Do you have a link to some source explaining or noting this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's stated explicitly, but if you examine the detailed description of how implicit rules are matched, here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html you will find (in step 5) that make first tries all the implicit rules to see if any of them match; a rule matches if the target matches and the prerequisite exists.  In your case, the `%:%.c` target matches and the prerequisite exists, so the rule is used.  Only if step 5 fails to find a match will make try step 6, which will try recursively (sub-step 4).

Answer (score 0):

The other implicit rules are being used because they can. The `.c` file exists and so it can be used to build the executable.

There are multiple ways to fix this:

1. Add the `$(obj_lib)` as a dependency of `$(targets)`. This will cause Make to ensure that the library `.o` files are linked into the main executable, solving that problem. However, this can still use the implicit rule, so it does not address the 2nd part of the question.
2. **Prevent Make from using the implicit rules.** This is the solution that I found that works best for my use-case. This can be done by adding the following to the end of the Makefile.

   ```
   # Delete implicit rules that could be used to create the executable.
   %: %.c
   %: %.o
   # Indicate that Make doesn't need to delete any intermediate objects. (Optional)
   .SECONDARY:
   ```

Here is a demonstration of this example before and after the change:

```
=============================================================
$ ls
Makefile  add.c  main1.c  main2.c  make.log
=============================================================
$ cat Makefile 
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration

targets := main1 main2
obj_targets := $(patsubst %,%.o,$(targets))

src_lib := add.c
obj_lib := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(src_lib))

all: $(targets)
%: %.o $(obj_lib)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -static -o $@ $^

# .PHONY: all
# # Delete implicit rules that could be used to create the executable.
# %: %.c
# %: %.o
# # Indicate that Make doesn't need to delete any intermediate objects.
# .SECONDARY:
=============================================================
$ make
gcc -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration    main1.c   -o main1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBsxlMV.o: in function `main':
main1.c:(.text.startup+0x11): undefined reference to `add'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: main1] Error 1
=============================================================
$ code Makefile 
=============================================================
$ cat Makefile 
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration

targets := main1 main2
obj_targets := $(patsubst %,%.o,$(targets))

src_lib := add.c
obj_lib := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(src_lib))

all: $(targets)
%: %.o $(obj_lib)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -static -o $@ $^

.PHONY: all
# Delete implicit rules that could be used to create the executable.
%: %.c
%: %.o
# Indicate that Make doesn't need to delete any intermediate objects.
.SECONDARY:
=============================================================
$ make
gcc -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration   -c -o main1.o main1.c
gcc -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration   -c -o add.o add.c
gcc -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -static -o main1 main1.o add.o
gcc -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration   -c -o main2.o main2.c
gcc -O2 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -static -o main2 main2.o add.o
=============================================================
$
```

Comment: It's odd that you're answering your own question.  This answer is not quite right.  It's true that if no other rule can be found to build a target then a default rule will be used.  But presumably you DO want to use some other rule, so removing the default rule won't help you: if make devolved to the default rule, then removing the default rule will result in an error because make doesn't know how to build the target.  So the real problem is that make is not finding your rule: that is totally unrelated to whether the default rule exists or not.

Comment: Please try to reproduce this from the example given and let me know if you see the behaviour you expect. If you do then please let me know which version of Make you are using. I am using GNU Make 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 and I do not see this behaviour. When I run make using the example posted without this change, it uses the default rule. When I disable the default rule as noted in this answer, it uses the rule I defined. This suggests that it is not devolving to the default rule since no other rule is available, but is instead preferring the default rule.

Comment: Additionally, with regards to answering my own question, I was able to figure out how to make it work through experimentation and wanted to document it so that any users who might hit the same issue would be able to resolve it. However I am not confident in my understanding of why this issue is happening, which is why I have not accepted the answer yet. I'm hoping someone else will come by with more insight into why removing the default rule actually does help in this case.